# How to get price and other product details from Flipkart or Other Shopping Apps Product Detail Page in Android App

Tags: android, e-commerce

I am trying to develop an app which will show similar products on the 
e-commerce apps like Flipkart or Amazon.

[Fairbuy Shopping App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fairbuy.allinoneshoppingapp.compareprice.bestprice.wishlist.flipkartsale.amazonindia&hl=en) is doing the same thing with ease.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Flip-kart and Amazon provides Affiliate APIs to fetch all this data.By using this you will get all price and product etc.
Check API Documentation of Flip-kart [https://affiliate.flipkart.com/api-docs/af_overview.html][1]  and Amazon at https://affiliate-program.amazon.in/][1]